# Do clients of cleaner fish queue up?

Tags: ethology, behaviour, ichthyology, altruism, symbiosis

I can't remember if I saw it in a cartoon, a documentary, or both, but the notion is that the clients of [cleaner fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaner_fish) wait in line to be cleaned. "Clients" means the fish (or other aquatic animals) who are cleaned by cleaner fish.

I tried to find a study whose sole purpose is to confirm that client fish wait their turn to be cleaned by cleaner fish, but I only found articles that seem to refer to this while studying other cleaner fish behaviour.

Statements I came across that support the notion:

- Most photographs of fish in coral reef are at cleaner stations because the fish are waiting there which allows photographers time to photograph.
- Cleaner fish "[have a positive impact on local reef fish diversity](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1809949/pdf/14667394.pdf)", which could imply many different fish come and may not attack each other to benefit from the cleaner fish. This one's more of a stretch.
- "[Others wait no longer than 30 seconds before searching for cleaners elsewhere.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_altruism#cite_note-Eibel-Eibesfeldt-5)" The source is German, so I can't go deeper.

Do fish wait in line to be cleaned by cleaner fish?

Side question: Is this an example of [reciprocal altruism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_altruism)?